# Python : Compare date strings without using built in functions or libraries

Tags: python, string, date

I would like to know whether we can compare two date strings in Python without using any built in functions in Python or libraries.
For example:
    25/01/2017>12/12/2017

Which is actually false but it returns true.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not try "not to use built in functions or libraries" unless this is for a school assignment. And if it is, you have to reveiw up to which point you can't use "builti n functions" - since the correct comparison involves spliting the day, month and year components, and either converting them to integers, or reassambling the date string in a way that is actually comparable - but all oft his requires a couple "built in functions"

Comment: "but it returns true." So you have it already started? Would you mind telling us what you already have so that we can more easily tell you what you did wrong instead of re-writing it ourselves?

Comment: is this a school assignment? don't ask stackoverflow to do your homework

Answer (score 1):

```
def compare(date1, date2):
    d1, m1, y1 = map(int, date1.split('/'))
    d2, m2, y2 = map(int, date2.split('/'))

    return (y1, m1, d1) > (y2, m2, d2)
```

This does use the `map` function. If you don't want to use that for some reason, you could do this:

```
def compare(date1, date2):
    date1_parts = date1.split('/')
    d1, m1, y1 = int(date1_parts[0]), int(date1_parts[1]), int(date1_parts[2])

    date2_parts = date2.split('/')
    d2, m2, y2 = int(date2_parts[0]), int(date2_parts[1]), int(date2_parts[2])

    return (y1, m1, d1) > (y2, m2, d2)
```

Now this does still use `str.split` and `int` (not really a built-in function, but it's not clear what your constraints are). You could keep going with trying to eliminate some of this, but I'll just stop there :)

Comment: Ah, nice. This is much prettier than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can if the date-string will be in a format that respects dictionary order (alphabetical order), such as: "yyyymmdd" or "yyyy/mm/dd".

Example:

```
d1 = "20170101"
d2 = "20170102"

print (d2 > d1) # True
print (d2 < d1) # False
print (d2 == d1) # False
```

**UPDATE:**

If you want to compare strings that have the same format like in the example, we can improve Miket's answer to be a bit more elegant by using tuple comparison:

```
def compare(dateOne, dateTwo):
    #Break up the date into its components
    day = int(dateOne[0:2])
    month = int(dateOne[3:5])
    year = int(dateOne[6:10])

    dayTwo = int(dateTwo[0:2])
    monthTwo = int(dateTwo[3:5])
    yearTwo = int(dateTwo[6:10])

    return (year, month, day) > (yearTwo, monthTwo, dayTwo)
```

Comment: Except that OP's year is last.

Comment: @CoryMadden I think you've missed the words "For example" before the example dates that the OP used in the question ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the given dates are strictly in that format, you can parse the strings out as such.

```
def compare(dateOne, dateTwo):
    #Break up the date into its components
    day = int(dateOne[0:2])
    month = int(dateOne[3:5])
    year = int(dateOne[6:10]))

    dayTwo = int(dateTwo[0:2])
    monthTwo = int(dateTwo[3:5])
    yearTwo = int(dateTwo[6:10]))

    #Compare the years first
    if(year > yearTwo):
        return True
    elif(year < yearTwo):
        return False
    else:
        #If the years are equal, then compare the months
        if(month > monthTwo):
            return True
        elif(month < monthTwo):
            return False
        else:
            #If the days are equal, return False since it's strictly greater, else, return the appropriate value. 
            if(day > dayTwo):
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

Given the values

```
compare("25/01/2017","12/12/2017")
```

It'll be `False`. This function compares the left-operand date to see if it's greater than the right-operand date.

Comment: Note you can just use a tuple comparison instead of those three nested if statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
def compare(d1, d2):
    for x, y in list(zip(map(int, d1.split('/')), map(int, d2.split('/'))))[::-1]:
        if x != y:
            return x > y
```

It starts with the year, if both years are equal we move on to the month. If both months are equal then we move on to the day. If date1's month/year/day is bigger than date2's month/year/day it returns `True` and exits the loop immediately.

Or, make it one line using `all`.

```
def compare(d1, d2):
    return all(x > y for x, y in list(zip(map(int, d1.split('/')), map(int, d2.split('/'))))[::-1])
```

Comment: nice. but a whole lot of built-in functions.  If the OP could use them, they may as well use a time module.

Comment: `zip`, `map`, `int`, `split` are all "built-in" functions I imagine.

Comment: Well, in that case everything is a built in function. I assumed it to mean no imports.

Comment: You could just use one branch in an if statement and say `if x != y: return x > y`.